# Implement convert From trait with additional argument

Tags: struct, rust

I have a situation where I have 2 structs

```
struct A {
  pub one: number;
  pub two: number;
}

struct AWithThree {
  pub one: number;
  pub two: number;
  pub three: number;
}
```

And I want to often convert `A` structs into `AWithThree` structs after calculating the `three` field. Note that in my actual code, both these structs have many more fields than shown here.

It becomes tedious though to always manually type each field that I need in the conversion in a function that takes in an `A` struct and return an `AWithThree` struct.

```
AWithThree {
   one: a.one,
   two: a.two,
   three: calculateThree(a),
}
```

I'd ideally like to be able to just do

```
AWithThree {
   ..a,
   three: calculateThree(a),
}
```

This is something that Typescript supports which makes struct mappings really easy since the required fields are automatically checked. But it seems that Rust doesn't support this.

---

So that's why I turned to implementing the `From` trait, but the required method of the `From` trait is only allowed to take in the type we're converting from

```
fn from(T) -> Self
```

I instead though wanted to be able to do

```
fn from(T, additional_arg: S) -> Self
```

where in my example above, `additional_arg` would be the value for `three` that I would then use to constuct the `AWithThree` struct from the `A` struct. I don't want to calculate the value of `three` inside the From since I want the calling function to pass it in.

Is there a better way to do easy struct conversion in Rust?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from adding `fn from(T, additional_arg: S) -> Self` just as a normal method, not via the `From` trait. Converting from one type to another isn't a special process in Rust, its all just functions.

Comment: `From` is just a widely-used *convention* for creating `U` from `T` (potentially in a generic setting), but your use doesn't fit that pattern so you shouldn't force it to. See stuff like [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html?search=#method.from_raw_parts) which uses 3 arguments. Instead of just `from` (which could be confusing), you can call it `from_a`

Comment: You can also implement From for the tuple type `(T,S)`.